# Immutable Tree Map for Java?

Tags: java, treemap, immutable.js, immutable-collections

I am looking for an implementation of an immutable Tree Map in Java, that allows for copy-on-write style modifications with sharing of identical parts. So, in essence exactly what [ImmutableJS](https://facebook.github.io/immutable-js/) does for JavaScript, just for Java.

If anyone happens to be unfamiliar with how ImmutableJS works, here is what I would like it to be in Java:

```
ImmutableTreeMap<String, String> map = new ImmutableTreeMap<>();
ImmutableTreeMap<String, String> map1 = map.put("hello", "world");
ImmutableTreeMap<String, String> map2 = map1.put("foo", "bar");
// the base maps should still remain the same
assertEquals(0, map.size());
assertEquals(1, map1.size());
```

In the above example, `map2` would not copy the part of the tree that stores `hello -> world`, it would re-use that part.

Is there any such implementation available, or do I have to go ahead and create one from scratch?

Comment: don't get it: when map1 is immutable, why sould it copy the map for me? This would do almost the same: `map =new HashMap(); map.put("hello","world"); map1= new HashMap(map); map2.put("foo", "bar");`

Comment: Yes, except that `map1 = new HashMap(map)` creates a real copy of the data in `map`, which is what I want to avoid. `map1` should share the data structure with `map` when possible (because it is immutable).

Comment: The term you are looking for is a _persistent_ map implementation.  Searching for that will help.

Comment: @LouisWasserman Thanks. I've never heard the term "persistent" in this context. To me, a "persistent tree" is a disk-based tree, e.g. a B-Tree.
Thanks to your hint, I was able to find this library, which will do nicely for my purposes: https://github.com/hrldcpr/pcollections

Answer (score 3, accepted):

your looking for a 'persistent' hash map, also called 'hash array mapped trie'.

one should note that a 'tree' is not the same thing as a 'trie' data structure.

you will find a few java HAMTs including ones from paguro, pcollections and javaslang projects, or you can use the canonical ones from clojure or scala compiled for the jvm

Comment: Indeed. I ended up implementing one on my own actually. It was a very interesting and insightful exercise.